# How do I access an element in a tuple that is stored in a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

```
song_lyrics_per_year={year:[(song, singer, lyrics),(song2, singer2, lyrics2)...], year2: ....}
```

Hello, I have a dict with year as keys and as values lists of tuples (consisting of song, singer, lyrics). 
No, I need to access all 3 elements separately and parse them into a list

```
onlysongs=[]
onlyartists=[]
```

However, all my tries have failed so far, including list comprehensions and codes that were suggested here.

Shouldn't this work?

```
for item in song_lyrics_per_year.values():
    onlyartists.append(item[1])
```

In response, I get an "IndexError: list index out of range"

Only a few weeks into Python and I went through all old answers on this topic and tried the solutions...they did not work, unfortunately.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: As @Hitobat mentioned in his answer, this is a doctor's of lists of tuples. You've only gotten to the list. You need to go one layer deeper.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing 1 level of list. Try something like:

```
for songs_in_single_year in song_lyrics_per_year.values():
    for song in songs_in_single_year:
        onlyartists.append(song[1])
```

Comment: To keep track of duplicates you can make ```onlyartitsts = collections.Counter()``` and replace ```onlyartists.append(song[1])``` with ```onlyartists.update((song[1],))```. That will give a dictionary with artitst and his correspondent number of hits.

Comment: Thanks hitobat & @accdias I really appreciate the replies and explanations

Comment: Oh, if you don't want dups I think using a set instead of a list would be better.

Answer (score 0):

```
for value in song_lyrics_per_year.values():
    for i in range(0,len(value)-1):
        onlysongs.append(value[i][0])
        onlyartists.append(value[i][1])
```

Thanks for the edit @Austin.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be clearer this way:

```
for year in song_lyrics_per_year:
    for song_lyric in song_lyrics_per_year[year]:
        song, singer, lyrics = song_lyric
        if singer not in onlyartists:
            onlyartists.append(singer)
```

Edited: to keep track of how often an artist appears you can use collections.Counter(). Here is a complete example:

```
from collections import Counter

singers = Counter()
years = { 
    2018: [
        ('Title1', 'Singer1', 'Lyrics1'),
        ('Title2', 'Singer1', 'Lyrics2')
    ],
    2019: [
        ('Title3', 'Singer3', 'Lyrics3')
    ]
}

for year in years:
    for song in years[year]:
        title, singer, lyrics = song
        singers.update((singer,))

for singer, hits in singers.most_common():
    print(singer, hits)
```

And here is the output:

```
Singer1 2
Singer3 1
```

Comment: This is a nice complete solution with no duplicates. You could also use a set to avoid that as well, as long as order doesn't matter.

Comment: By using collections.Counter() you have some good collateral effects. Let's say you want to know the Top 10 artists based on number of hits. To achieve that you just call singers.most_common(10), and it will give you that list.